# google line chart not able to show each date

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization, linechart

I was trying to use google linechart for displaying data from my database with corresponding dates on haxis and score on vaxis i achieved that but i want to show dates like 1,2,3,4,5...30 for a month and show weeks if more than 1 month on haxis but its not giving dates like that it gives interval of 7 days for a month but thats not my requirement. i tried using gridlines but not working can anybody help me plz...
here is my code

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);


function drawTable()
{
    var data=new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date','date');
    data.addColumn('number','score');
    data.addRows([
    <?php 
    $output1=array();
      $output2=array();


    foreach ($gra as $key) {
        $t1=$key;
        $output1[]=$t1;
    } 
    foreach ($dated as $key2) {
        $t2=$key2;
        $output2[]=$t2;
    }
    $combine=array();
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($output1) && $i<sizeof($output2); $i++)
    {
        $combine[]="[".$output2[$i].",".$output1[$i]."]";
    }
    echo implode(",", $combine);

  ?>

  ]);

  var options={

    title:'Fitness Analysis',
    vAxis:{title:"Fitness Score", viewWindowMode:'explicit',
 viewWindow: {
   max:500,
    min:0
  } },
    hAxis:{title:"Dates",viewWindowMode:'explicit',
    gridlines:{count:30},
  viewWindow: {min: new Date(2013, 8, 1),max: new Date(2013, 9, 1) }}

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
    chart.draw(data, options);  
   }
```